# How can I know if a type of content is moderated?

Tags: 8, workflows

I'm trying to find out if a type of content (not a node) is being moderated. How can I determine it?

For example:

```
function MY_MODULE_form_node_type_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
   $content_type = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity(); // $content_type is a Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType
}
```

I can't find a way to find out if this type of content is being moderated by some type of workflow.

Comment: You sure you are not mixing up terms? Content type is a bundle to be used for many nodes and a content type can't be moderated as far as I know. But nodes can. And they then are connected to a moderation state entity I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get that from [`ModerationInformation:: shouldModerateEntitiesOfBundle()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21content_moderation%21src%21ModerationInformation.php/function/ModerationInformation%3A%3AshouldModerateEntitiesOfBundle/8.8.x), via the `content_moderation.moderation_information` service:

```
$moderation_info = \Drupal::service('content_moderation.moderation_information');
$entity_type = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinition('node');
if ($moderation_info->shouldModerateEntitiesOfBundle($entity_type, $content_type->id())) {
  // ...
}
```